# Referencing java.io.tmpdir inside web.xml file

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

How can I map some servlet `init-param` to something like `java.io.tmpdir/test`, for example?

I have already tried `${java.io.tmpdir}/test` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: If you're working with init parameter on web.xml, you can use ${initParam.myCustomPath}... at web.xml you'll have some like this: <context-param>
<param-name>myCustomPath</param-name>
<param-value>/tmp/my-app/</param-value>
</context-param>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't built-in to Servlets.  You'll  have to implement this in your code.  the Spring library has a class for this:  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ServletContextPropertyUtils.html.

I've also seen people override ServletContext to provide this support:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/484445/Servlets/java/access-System-Properties-determine-param